# Poincarè distance in python

Tags: python

I have some bidimensional tensors in python and I want to calculate the Poincarè distance because I'm working with these geometry.

On Wikipedia I found [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/9eedf69ec11c340ab0b2b82303fb67beac51f379), [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/13ff5dd3e2f84acedf3b409eaa27173796da75d8) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#Metric_and_curvature).

So I tried to implement [first](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/9eedf69ec11c340ab0b2b82303fb67beac51f379), [second](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/13ff5dd3e2f84acedf3b409eaa27173796da75d8) and [third](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#Metric_and_curvature) and to evaluate the correctness I calculated the distance between one tensor ([0.2048, -0.9201]) and itself.

The first gave me Tensor = [0.8814], the second 5.5443 and the third 0.8813.

I post even the codes:

```
from numpy.linalg import norm

def first(tensor1, tensor2):
return np.arcsinh(np.cosh(tensor1[1]) * 
                     np.cosh(tensor2[0] - tensor1[0])*
                     np.cosh(tensor2[1]) - 
                     np.sinh(tensor1[1])*
                     np.sinh(tensor2[1]))

def second(tensor1, tensor2):
return np.arcsinh(
                1 + (2*(norm(np.dot(tensor1, tensor2)) ** 2))
                / ((1 - norm(tensor1) ** 2)*(1 - norm(tensor2) ** 2)))

def third(tensor1, tensor2):
return np.arcsinh(
        1 + (2*(norm(tensor1 - tensor2) ** 2))
        / ((1 - norm(tensor1) ** 2)*(1 - norm(tensor2) ** 2)))
```

Which one i have to use?
Why my formules are wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The equations for both 1) and 3) have `arcosh`, but you have `arcsinh`...

Comment: Ciao Manuel,
I'd suggest you to use a specific math software to do so. You might like [sagemath/colcalc](http://www.sagemath.org/). There is a special package for Differential Geometry called sage manifold. Here the Hyperbolic Model [doc](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/hyperbolic_geometry/sage/geometry/hyperbolic_space/hyperbolic_model.html).